# Can I restore a folder that suddenly disappeared?

Tags: files, data-recovery, restore, undelete

This sometimes occurs with my laptop when I physically close it.

The laptop crashes. When I open it afterwards, the screen goes black.

This time, I had some files open, and when I rebooted the laptop, a complete folder was missing.

It's really odd that this folder suddenly disappeared. It's not in the trash, the trash contain files that I sent there before it occurred, and the `history` bash command shows that no `rm` command was committed on that folder.

Comment: In case your filesystem is FAT, ext2 or NTFS, you may want to check `TestDisk` for that purpose. You can analyze folders and restore their content.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link on how to restore files that where deleted by accident or crash: 
https://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_from_accidently_deleted_files_or_crashed_drives_in_ubuntu

Another good option might be PhotoRec: 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Yet another great source on data recovery: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Good luck!